# I'am creating a new reactjs application using " npx create-react-app" , and when it's done and trying to run it using "npm start" , I get an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

This is the full error message

```
./src/index.js 1:58
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:58)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/fcss/Desktop/Hussein's Projects/react-firebase-crud/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
|
```

Comment: Try running `npm install` just to make sure your packages are update

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are using " ' " in your path name "Hussein's Projects", change it to "Husseins_Projects" and everything should work
You can read more about it [here](https://www.csudh.edu/web-services/web-standards/file-folder-naming/)